# Routing and two controllers in AngulatJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes

I'm using `$routeProvider` to routes in my application. In `index.html` looks like this:

```
<html ng-app="...">
    <head>
      <!-- import -->
    </head>
    <body>
      <div ng-controller="LoginController"> 
        <button ng-click="login">Login</button>
      </div>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that `ng-click="login"` never kicks in. Function `login` is not invoked in LoginController (I have `$scope.login = function() {...}`).

How can I make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect , you need to call the function within `ng-click` but are missing the `()` that will invoke it:

```
<button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<button ng-click="login">Login</button>
```

To

```
<button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
```

So you are actually calling the function, and invoking it.